# No module named math - Pycharm

Tags: python, math, import, pycharm

I try to import math but it doesnt work. I get the error: " No module named math "

I used math before, so it is strange that is not working now. Also, I can import random and pygame, but not math.

This is a screenshot of the settings.

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdb9w.png)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gADI.png)

Comment: It might just be the editor. Running the code is probably fine, although `sin`, `cos`, etc. need importing explicitly.

Comment: Indeed possible. The program runs even with those errors on red.

Comment: Probably means that pycharm is not configured properly. Should make sure it is using the right interpreter for the project.

Comment: Updating PyCharm solved it for me!